# Sequel Ruby reading bytea data type

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel, bytea

I am trying to decode a json mime type stored in bytea column in postgres using sequel. I remember I used some kind of method passing it mime type and data. But I cannot find it in my code and documentation.

I have bytea column and info about mime type (text/json). I would like to get the json :)

Please any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is .lit method, I got it, easy and overseen by me.